# Combine factor levels in an ff object

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

I often categorise times into day/night time using `cut()`.  Because `cut()` doesn't understand that clock times go around zero, I first divide the hours into three groups (night either side of day), and then merge the two "night" factor levels.  This can be done by giving the same "night" value twice to `levels()`.  E.g.

```
x <- c(4, 10, 23) # i.e. 4 am, 10 am, 11 pm
x <- cut(x
         , breaks = c(0, 6, 22, 23)
         , include.lowest = FALSE
         , labels = c("night2", "day", "night1"))
# [1] night2 day    night1
# Levels: night2 day night1

levels(x) <- c("night", "day", "night")
x
# [1] night day   night
# Levels: night day
```

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with a huge dataset in an `ff` object:

```
require(ff)
require(ffbase)

y <- ff(c(4, 10, 23))
y <- ff(cut(y
            , breaks = c(0, 6, 22, 23)
            , include.lowest = FALSE
            , labels = c("night2", "day", "night1")))
y
# ff (open) integer length=3 (3) levels: night2 day night1
#    [1]    [2]    [3] 
# night2 day    night1 

levels(y) <- c("night", "day", "night")
y
# ff (open) integer length=3 (3) levels: night day night
#  [1]   [2]   [3] 
# night day   night
```

Note that in this case, `levels()` has retained three factor levels, two of which have the same label. `recodeLevels` looked promising but doesn't quite do the same thing:

```
y <- recodeLevels(y, c("night", "day", "night"))
y
# ff (open) integer length=3 (3) levels: night day night
# [1] [2] [3] 
# NA  day NA
```

I've also tried duplicate "night" labels within `cut()` (actually `cut.ff()`), but it still returns three levels, plus a warning that duplicate levels in factors are deprecated.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Have you tried `recodeLevels(y, c("night", "day"))`. FYI: `recodelevels` is part of package ff, not part of ffbase.

Comment: Ta, edited to fix that.  I tried your suggestion on its own and got `NA day NA`.  Then I tried it after `levels(y) <- c("night", "day", "night")`, which retains the three levels `night day night`.  Did you mean something else?

Comment: Added it as an answer instead of in the comments.

Comment: Also, you can use distinct capitalization and then re-label to the identical capitalization. 

    `y = cut(0:23, c(-Inf,8,19,Inf), c('night','day','Night'));`
    `levels(y) = tolower(levels(y))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for. Use `recodeLevels` from package ff

```
require(ff)
y <- c(4, 10, 23)
y <- ff(cut(y, breaks = c(0, 6, 22, 23), include.lowest = FALSE, 
            labels = c("night2", "day", "night1")))
levels(y) <- c("night", "day", "night")
alllevs <- c("night", "day")
y <- recodeLevels(y, alllevs)
levels(y) <- alllevs
y
ff (open) integer length=3 (3) levels: night day
[1]   [2]   [3] 
night day   night
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be too simple, but why not just do:

```
x <- c(4, 10, 23)
y = c("day", "night")[(x <= 6 | x > 22) + 1]
y
[1] "night" "day"   "night"
```

Comment: Great solution to this particular case.  It would be nice to have a more general solution for merging factor levels.  Sometimes I use morning/afternoon/night.  Other times I merge "not available" with "not used", etc.

Comment: I think the best general approach if there are duplicates is to just refactor the whole vector: `y = factor(as.character(y))`